# Как получить текст ошибки запроса Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

У меня есть следующий код, в котором я отлавливаю код ответа и бросаю собственные исключения.

```
    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .addInterceptor(chain -> {
                Request.Builder ongoing = chain.request().newBuilder();


                //...


                //build request
                Request request = ongoing.build();
                Response response = null;

                //process request
                try {
                    response = chain.proceed(request);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new NetworkException(e.getMessage());
                }


                if (response.code() == 400){
                    throw new ClientRequestException();
                }


                return response;
            })
            .build();

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(httpClient)
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(new NullOnEmptyConverterFactory())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Но в таком случае, мне нужно добавлять сообщение исключения самостоятельно,
вопрос могу ли я как то из `response` получить текст ошибки которую мне отдает сервер?

Comment: Вроде как-то так: `response.errorBody().string()`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб этот метода есть у Response из Retrofit,  а из пакета OkHttp его нету, в этом то и проблема!

Comment: А если просто response.toString()?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб дает тип ошибки но не содержимое Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=http://site.com}

Comment: А метода `body()` нет?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Ооо, работает, а я почему то пытался по аналогии делать и искал метода error() , errorBody() ... Можете  опубликовать ответ!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тело ответа, где содержится ошибка может быть получено так:

```
 String body = response.body();
```